# Extending Eloquent model with different model

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

```
<?php

class Page extends Eloquent {

}

class Article extends Page {
    function __construct($attributes = []) {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->where('type', 'article');
    }
}

$articles = Article::all();
// SELECT * FROM pages WHERE type = 'article'
```

The page table has many types of data, I want to separate these data by model class, I tried the above query but `where()` function isn't even being called in `__constructor()`

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

class Page extends Eloquent {

}

class Article extends Page {
    function __construct($attributes = []) {
       if($attributes) {
          $attributes['type'] = 'article';
       }
        parent::__construct($attributes);

    }
    public function newQuery() {
        return parent::newQuery()->where('type', 'article');
   }    

}

$articles = Article::all();
// SELECT * FROM pages WHERE type = 'article'
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply want implement `scope` in `Model`. So check [`Query Scope`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) but It must be defined in the `model` class. If you want a seperate class that uses that `scope` as the basis for querying check out `global scope`. https://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/

Comment: I will have to create 1 `Trait` and 1 `Scope Class` each time. Is this the only solution?

Comment: If you want a seperate class then yes It is. `Global Scope` is the only option. Most of the time `query scope` will do the trick.

Comment: your class will have more methods but you won't need to worry about seperate class.

Comment: This answer is more correct than the accepted one and should be accepted.